# Handling Migrated Questions when User deletes the associated account

Tags: discussion

So [this](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5040/long-term-vaccine-studies-of-subjective-characteristics/) is the second time I've watched this personally, and I was wondering if there was a general way that such questions should be handled.

My general impression of what happens is that a question get's migrated to us, but then the user decides they don't really want to be part of the community and delete the account.  I feel like even if we answer the questions, doesn't this still add to our "unanswered" question total, and therefore harm the stats of this site?

This is probably not a significant portion of questions, but if they were ones that could clearly be deleted, maybe that would be better?  I don't have a strong opinion ether way.

Comment: I think that's just because SE doesn't create an account on migration. The user has to do that manually. For what's it worth, as soon as an answer has a positive score, it counts as answered. No need for anyone to accept it.

Comment: (I'd write an answer with links to meta, but I am in an actual waiting room right now ;-))

Comment: So then if it's got an answer that's +1 or higher it counts as answered?  That's awesome, I didn't understand that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out [in comments](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/559/handling-migrated-questions-when-user-deletes-the-associated-account#comment3728_559), there is not necessarily any account deletion going on here, just a migrated question by a user who has not created an account on Health.SE. From [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) :

> If a user who has participated in the question does not have an account on the target site, their username is displayed as plain text until they create an account

As for tallying `Unanswered Questions`, per Meta.SE this includes: ["questions that have no answers with a positive score nor an accepted answer. (That includes questions with no answers at all.)"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18871/272257)

See also: [OK, Now Define “Answered”](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/).